# Exclude a queryset from bigger queryset in django without hitting the database

Tags: python, django

I have a queryset of all objects of a model. Iterating over the objects, I am removing updating rows with value repetition in a column. So without having to hit the database again, i want to remove the updated rows from the bigger queryset.

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: It's better to let SQL filter the original list.  It's optimized to execute WHERE clauses more efficiently than you will.

Comment: That is true, Actually I tried similar thing in SQL but that was taking too much time and cpu usage. I am not good in SQl :(

Comment: Too much time?  That would suggest to me that your schema is missing indexes.  Run EXPLAIN PLAN on the SQL and look for a table scan.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to provide more information about your specific use case, but in general, Django defers the evaluation of QuerySets until they are actually needed. If you are able to construct a QuerySet of the exclusion set independently of the larger QuerySet, you can call the `.exclude()` method and generate one large query instead of two smaller ones. For example:

```
excluded_set = Model.objects.filter(...)
large_set = Model.objects.filter().exclude(id__in=excluded_set)
```

Comment: No, I was asking about doing it without hitting the database

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but exclude, like filter, does not actually evaluate a queryset - does the `__in` lookup change that? Best I could find (see green box): https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#in